# Error: "This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app." - accessing a Report

Tags: reporting

I've created a Report for one of the users and when they are trying to access the Report, they are getting the error message: "**This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app.**"

The **Report Type = Opportunities** and the Report is saved in a folder the user has access to.

The **OWD for Opportunities = Public Read Only**.

I've checked the Profile. I even changed the Profile and the Role of the user and still didn't work.

I have created a different type of Report = Opportunities with Products and the user is able to access it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.